# Mat dialog components and directives not working in a "container" module

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am upgrading and existing angular 10 project to angular 11 and have run into the issue where in the module containing my dialogs is throwing errors

**The setup**: I have a main module called `protected-pages` and another module called `ui-dialogues`. `ui-dialogues` contains components that are material dialogues only and are imported into the `protected-pages` module and used in entry components.

**The problem**: I keep on getting errors such as

1. 'mat-dialog-actions' is not a known element .
2. Can't bind to 'mat-dialog-close' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
3. 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element.

---

Protected pages module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UiModule,
    CustomComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    AngularMaterialImporterModule,
    UiDialoguesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(route),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [ProtectedPageFrameComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
})
export class ProtectedPagesModule {}
```

---

Angular material importer module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    ScrollingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
})
export class AngularMaterialImporterModule {}
```

---

Ui dialogues module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AngularMaterialImporterModule,
    CustomComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class UiDialoguesModule {}
```

If any other clarification is required please do let know.

---

**Edit** : I performed a complete wipe of the `node_modules` folder in the project and ran a `yarn` command to install the packages again and its fixed automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MatDialogModule as well to the list of modules present in AngularMaterialImporterModule.

```js
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Above is the right import statement. Hope it helps. Let me know if it worked!

Comment: i had already done that , forgot to update the question, please check again